# What's the best way to build a schema from an XML/JSON file?

Tags: saxon

For the case of not having an XSD file, we need to build up a schema of a data file to make it easy for users to create XPath statements. So clearly we need to walk the entire document and from that build up the schema structure.

We have to walk everything to handle the case of (<middle> not in the first node):

```
<name>
  <first>George</first>
  <last>Washington</last>
</name>
<name>
  <first>Harry></first>
  <middle>S</middle>
  <last>Truman</last>
</name>
```

And if at all possible, get the data type (JSON has this). Is there an example of how to do this anywhere in Saxon 10.1?

Answer (score 0):

For any given instance document, there are many possible schemas. There are quite a few tools out there that generate a schema from an instance document, and they produce different (and sometimes hilarious) results. For example some might decide that the middle initial of a US President has to be "B", "F", or "S", or that the first name has to be at least 5 characters long. Many would decide that an O'Reilly can never be President.

Many years ago I wrote a DTD generator which produces a DTD for an instance document which is the same kind of exercise, but simpler because it's only inferring complex types, not simple types. It just involves including as many practical heuristics as you can come up with by feeding it a selection of test cases and examining the results.

So there's no right or "best" answer; it's not a well-defined requirement; quite a few people have written tools that do it; and if you want to study how they do it: well, some of the tools are open source.

I would question the assumption: "we need to build up a schema of a data file to make it easy for users to create XPath statements". Yes, a schema of some form is useful; but a schema synthesised from instance documents isn't half as useful as a schema written by a human being who understands the data model.

Comment: "isn't half as useful as a schema written by a human being who understands the data model" - yes but business users don't have the knowledge to do this right. And many of our users are business users and they can't get the tech team to deliver a schema.

Comment: BTW - I have code that does this on the fly in our program that works great. The problem is it uses the .Net XML runtime and therefore can't handle JSON.

Comment: I put up an example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100478/is-this-the-best-way-to-get-all-elements-attributes-in-an-xml-file-using-saxon that works. Don't know if it's an optimum implementation.